# Script executes properly in ExtendScript Toolkit, but not Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I've written a script that takes a selection of multiple paths, duplicates them, and applies "Object > Envelope distort > Make with top object" on each duplicate of the bottom path with every other path in the selection using an action (don't believe there's anything in the DOM for interacting with envelopes directly). So I start with this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBKZs.png

It works perfectly in ExtendScript Toolkit, giving me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLdRz.png

But if I execute the script from within Illustrator, I get this mess:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/caL0u.png

Here's my code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sel = app.activeDocument.selection;
var currentLayer = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

function envelope(){
    var arr = [];
    var bottomObject = sel[sel.length - 1];
    bottomObject.selected = false;
    for (i = 0; i < sel.length - 1; i++){
        arr.push(sel[i]);
        var newObjs = sel[i].duplicate();
        newObjs.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDBACKWARD)
    }

    currentLayer.hasSelectedArtwork = false;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var objectsToDistribute = bottomObject.duplicate();
        objectsToDistribute.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDTOBACK);
        arr[i].selected = true;
        objectsToDistribute.selected = true;
        app.doScript('Envelope all', 'scriptTest');
        }
}

envelope();
```

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5jjqalm93hdc2z/scriptTest.aia?dl=0) the action set. So why would I be getting different results from the same script? Is there a way to work around this from within Illustrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the line `currentLayer.hasSelectedArtwork = false;` into the loop. It's need to clear the selection for every iteration:

```
...

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    currentLayer.hasSelectedArtwork = false; // <------------- here

    var objectsToDistribute = bottomObject.duplicate();
    objectsToDistribute.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDTOBACK);
    arr[i].selected = true;
    objectsToDistribute.selected = true;
    app.doScript('Envelope all', 'scriptTest');
    }

...
```

And actually you don't need the action set.
It can be done via `app.executeMenuCommand('Make Envelope');`

Here is my version of the script:

```
var sel = app.activeDocument.selection;      // all the objects that have been selected
var lowest = sel[sel.length-1];              // the lowest object

for (var i=0; i<sel.length-1; i++) {
    var top       = sel[i].duplicate();      // make a copy of the next object
    var btm       = lowest.duplicate();      // make a copy of the lowest object
    app.selection = null;                    // deselect all
    top.selected  = true;                    // select the top copy
    btm.selected  = true;                    // select the bottom copy
    app.executeMenuCommand('Make Envelope'); // make Envenlope
}
```

The only difference: it transforms the lowest object among the selected objects.